# Given a Binary tree represented as a list, provide a UNIQUE list of leaves of the tree

Tags: prolog

How to provide a UNIQUE list of leaves of the tree using Prolog:
Example:

```
mytreeunique([a,[b,[a,[c,d]]]],X).
```

Yields `X=[a,b,c,d]`

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried: append([Head|Tail], List, [Head|Result]):-  
     append(Tail, List, Result).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mytreeunique([H|T],[H|R]):-
\+is_list(H),
mytreeunique(T,R),
\+member(H,R).

mytreeunique([H|T],R):-
\+is_list(H),
mytreeunique(T,R),
member(H,R).

mytreeunique([H|T],R):-
is_list(H),
mytreeunique(H,R1),
mytreeunique(T,R2),
append(R1,R2,R).

mytreeunique([],[]).
```

First case checks if head is element and adds it to result if not already added.

Second case skips the H if it is an element if already in result.

Third case checks if Head is a list, So It traverses through it and also goes through the rest of the list and appends the result together.

Fourth case is the base case.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mostafa! this problem took my whole day yestarday.. I used flatten and nonmember in the end. Your answer, so clear and simple. You're amazing! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem man.
It would also be great to mark my answer as the correct solution :)
I'm trying to gain some points ;)